# Photo not displaying in django html

Tags: django, python-3.x, image

I spent a few hours trying to find out what is going on but I can`t see why the photo is not displayed in my html file.

**Goal:** Display the profile photo of each user
**Issue:** Photo not displaying in django html

**detail.html**

```
<div class="col-sx-1 col-sm-5 text-right">
    <a href="{% url 'contacts:detail' contact.id %}">
       {% if contact.photo %}
          <img src="/{{ contact.photo.url }}" class="img-responsive">
       {% else %}
          <h3>No image to display</h3>
       {% endif %}
    </a>                        
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def create_contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.user = request.user
        contact.photo = request.FILES['photo']
        file_type = contact.photo.url.split('.')[-1]
        file_type = file_type.lower()
        if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
            context = {
                'contact': contact,
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
            }
            return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)
        contact.save()
        return render(request, 'contacts/detail.html', {'contact': contact})
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [...]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profileimage', blank = True)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: remove slash <img src="{{ contact.photo.url }}" class="img-responsive">

Comment: I have added it based on another post as it was not working previously. I have now removed it , and I still can`t see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to the main urls.py file. I hope this help.